# Using Series of variables in SQL Query using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Series of IDs:

```
ID:['A10','B10','C44'.......]
```

I am running a SQL query to extract information from a table. Currently, this is what I'm doing:

```
for s in ID:
  sqlquery="Select Name, Age, ID from table where ID=%s"
  result=cursor.execute(sqlquery,(s,))
```

But this is taking a lot of time since I have about 100 IDs stored in the Series. Is there anyway I can use the 'in' clause of SQL? Something like this:

```
 sqlquery="Select Name,Age, ID from table where ID in...."
```

How to use the Series ID in the above query? And how to execute it using Cursor?